# Drupal 7 user.tpl.php $account

Tags: drupal-7

In Drupal 6, if we want to know everything about the profile user, we print_r the $account variables. However, I just found out in Drupal 7, the $account variable is not available anymore. What is the new way to access the profile user's account information?

Answer (score 4):

Try this: `print_r($elements['#account']);`

When I put that in user-profile.tpl.php, I get an object like...

```
stdClass Object
(
    [uid] => 29
    [name] => user
    [pass] => 
    [mail] => user@example.com
    [theme] => 
    [signature] => 
    [signature_format] => 
    [created] => 1304866465
    [access] => 0
    [login] => 0
    [status] => 1
    [timezone] => 
    [language] => 
    [picture] => 
    [init] => 
    [data] => 
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [2] => authenticated user
        )
    [entity_view_prepared] => 1
```

)

(I found this by installing the [Devel](http://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and checking the available variables by putting `dsm(get_defined_vars());` in the template.)